# Set standard filter value for Boolean Filter in API Platform Bundle

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm searching a way to set the default value of a boolean filter (without setting the filter via GET-Parameters).
To make my question clearer: Instead of using this request

```
http://localhost/api/myclass?archived=0
```

I just want to get all non-archived objects by:

```
http://localhost/api/myclass
```

So I want to set a standard filter set (like I can also set a standard order filter set).

My favorite way is to use annotations. I couldn't find it in the api platform bundle docu.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\MyClass;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\BooleanFilter;

/**
 * MyClass
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_class")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\MyClass")
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"api_read", "api_read_v2"}},
 *          "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"api_write"}}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"archived"})
 */
class MyClass
{ ...
  /**
     * @var bool|null
     * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="archived", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $archived = 0;

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the BooleanFilter just allow you to filter your request by the value of your boolean.

For your problem maybe try something like this in annotation (without the nullable !) :

@ORM\Column(name="archived", type="boolean", options={"default":true})